# Using trigger magic inside usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I'm building a reusable control meant for editing specific class type. Suppose, that it looks like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The edited object will be provided by a dependency property and set as DataContext of the whole control. (It may be provided through DataContext as well, on the second thought).

I want the `TextBox` to be disabled, when there is no data provided. Is there a way to create some kind of trigger, which will automagically switch `Enabled` property, when there's no data available? (= either some `Data` dependency property is null or the `DataContext` is null) Or should I do all the logic from the code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer about triggers has already been given, I want to offer a solution using a converter as an alternative.
This converter takes into account the possibility of binding to a either a `Boolean` or `Visibility` property:

```
public class IsNotNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool result = (value != null);
        if (targetType == typeof(Visibility))
            return result ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// xaml namespace declaration
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Converters:IsNotNullConverter x:Key="IsNotNullConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Name</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsEnabled={Binding Name,
                            Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}"
                 Visibility={Binding Name,
                             Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have to say, that I like both answers; I'm choosing this though, because I already have some styles for controls and I'd have to do some `BasedOn` magic to make it work properly. It seems to be a little more versatile, because I won't have to create different styles for different kinds of controls I use.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that via Trigger. Simply compare DataContext with `x:Null` and set `IsEnabled` to false in that case via Setter.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
```

**UPDATE** (In case want to check DataContext of UserControl)

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

**NOTE** -

> UserControl's DataContext is automatically inherited by its child so
>   TextBox will inherit it unless you set it explicitly. However, not true for your custom DP unless you register with *FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits*.

Comment: Won't that check the value of `TextBox`'s `DataContext`? I want to bind to my `UserControl`'s `DataContext` (or its other DP)

Comment: You can achieve that via `DataTrigger`. See the update.

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. The solution with converters seems to fit my needs a little bit better though and that's why I accepted the other one.